# Strange behaviour of "Ctrl+." (ExpandSelection)

Tags: front-end, keyboard, linux

I have always used the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> keyboard shortcut (`ExpandSelection`) to select a group of text. Repeatedly pressing <kbd>.</kbd> (*whilst still holding* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) would select a growing area of text, up until the entire cell has been selected. Recently, I noticed that this shortcut does not behave as expected for me anymore. The sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> makes a small letter 'e' appear in the top left corner, where any subsequent is entered. This seems to be some edit window that can be escaped with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which enters the text at the current cursor position.

For example, here I typed: `Sin[x]`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (the 'e' window appears), `Cos` and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd> to escape that window and insert the text.

[image]

Can anyone explain this behaviour? I looked into my `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file and still have the expected line:
`Item[KeyEvent[".", Modifiers -> {Control}], "ExpandSelection"],`

I checked this behaviour in versions 12.3 and 13.0. I'm running Fedora 35 x86_64.

Comment: I would [report this](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback), it certainly seems like a bug

Comment: I do not reproduce this behavior with versions 12.3.1 and 13.0 on Windows 10 x64. I do not get the 'e' window.

Comment: That looks like you've managed to trigger your platform's Input Method Editor (IME).

Comment: Yes, I think it's a Linux specific issue. The problem must have appeared recently after a Linux kernel update.

Answer (score 7):

Solved it. In case someone runs into the same issue in the future, I'll describe here what I've done.

By typing `Ctrl+.` in Gedit, I found out this shortcut launches the emoji input menu (thanks to @ihojnicki for pointing out in the comments that what I was doing is launching an IME). Then, I followed this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452386/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts) to find out how to change that keybinding since it was not available under the standard Settings->Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts in Gnome.

I had to install `dconf-editor` instead. From there, I navigated to `/desktop/ibus/panel/emoji/hotkey` and had to change the keybinding from `Ctrl+.` to something else. Saved the changes, reloaded Mathematica, done.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem with an upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I searched a bit and found [a way to disable these emoji-editor shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372781/new-ctrl-period-key-sequence-default-in-21-10) `Ctrl-.` and `Ctrl-;`.  I used a variant of what they propose, running the following command in a terminal.  This leaves the emoji editor available as `Ctrl-Shift-e`.

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "['<Control><Shift>e']"
```